# How remove space between items in CarouselView-xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

How remove space between items in CarouselView-xamarin forms ?

I would like remove space between items, please

```
<control:CarouselView 
    x:FieldModifier="teste"
     ItemsSource="{Binding Itens}"
     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
    HeightRequest="150"
    WidthRequest="250"
     Position="{Binding Position}">
    <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <b:BehaviorCollection>
            <b:EventToCommand EventName="PositionSelected" Command="{Binding OnPositionSelectedCommand}" />
        </b:BehaviorCollection>
    </b:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <control:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <ContentView >   
                <AbsoluteLayout  WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50">
                        <StackLayout  Padding="10,10,10,10" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 1, 1, 1" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Titulo}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="{StaticResource CadastroBackground}" FontSize="40" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </AbsoluteLayout>
            </ContentView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </control:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</control:CarouselView>
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can control the space between the pages using the property InterPageSpacing. Set it to zero and this should solve your problem

Comment: Yes, but where do I use the property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the InterPageSpacing attriubte to the CarouselView control. This works for this CarouselView plugin [github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView](http://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView). You would add the attribute like this

```
<control:CarouselViewControl 
    InterPageSpacing="0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Itens}"
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
    HeightRequest="150"
    WidthRequest="250"
    Position="{Binding Position}">
    <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <b:BehaviorCollection>
            <b:EventToCommand EventName="PositionSelected" Command="{Binding OnPositionSelectedCommand}" />
        </b:BehaviorCollection>
    </b:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <control:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <ContentView >   
                <AbsoluteLayout  WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50">
                        <StackLayout  Padding="10,10,10,10" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 1, 1, 1" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Titulo}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="{StaticResource CadastroBackground}" FontSize="40" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </AbsoluteLayout>
            </ContentView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </control:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
</control:CarouselViewControl>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried it, it does not recognize as property of carouselView.

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep looking.

Comment: You might want to use this plugin https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView which support InterPageSpacing. If I am not mistaken, this plugin is supposed to become the new standard CarouselView in Xamarin.Forms